# Bind an observable property to a collection function?

Tags: javafx, collections, binding, kotlin, tornadofx

I have a class `Market` which contains a collection of `MarketUpdate` objects called `m_updates`. For the UI I am using type-safe builders to create columns in a tableview like so:

```
override val root = tableview<Market> {
    val sortedMarketList = SortedList<Market>(markets)
    sortedMarketList.comparatorProperty().bind(this.comparatorProperty())
    items = sortedMarketList
...
column("Strikes", Market::m_strikes)
...
```

The `m_strikes` property is just a SimpleIntegerProperty directly owned by a `Market` object. However, I need to be able to build columns like these:

```
...
column("Created At", Market::m_updates::first::m_time)
...

...
column("Last Update", Market::m_updates::last::m_time)
...
```

where `m_time` is a SimpleLongProperty owned by a `MarketUpdate` object. When a `Market` object is updated, a new `MarketUpdate` object is added to the end of the `m_updates` collection. This means that the binding needs to automatically transition from one object to another, and that the tableview needs to be notified and update itself to reflect the data in the new object. I think binding by way of the `first()` and `last()` functions of the collection as described above captures the idea in a very simple way, but it won't compile.

There are many properties like `m_strikes` and `m_time`. How can I achieve this gracefully?

Comment: I think I'm onto something at the moment using SimpleObjectProperty and a dummy object, but I'm not confident it will work properly once all the necessary adjustments are made. I'll post another comment once I'm able to test it.

Comment: The solution I was experimenting with was adding `val m_first = SimpleObjectProperty<MarketUpdate>(dummyMarketUpdate)` to the Market object, updating it when appropriate, and then changing the column line to read `column("Created At", Market::m_first::get)`. This requires the text to be set along the lines of `text = it.m_time.get().toString()` but that isn't a big deal.

Unfortunately, this solution prevents the sorting functionality of the table from working correctly. It may be trying to sort based on what was returned by m_first.get() instead of the text displayed in the cell.

Comment: Comparator lambda may have solved the sorting issue. Need to make sure that live data is sorted properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your use case, what you want to do is to create an observable value that represents the time property for the first and last updates in a given `Market` object. To do that, you can create an `objectBinding` based on  the `updates` list inside of each `Market` object, then extract the `first()` or `last()` element's `timeProperty`. In the following example, the TableView will update as soon as you augment the updates list in any `Market` object.

Bear in mind that the example requires each `Market` to have at least one update. If this isn't your case, make sure to handle null accordingly.

```
class Market {
    val updates = FXCollections.observableArrayList<MarketUpdate>()
}

class MarketUpdate {
    val timeProperty = SimpleObjectProperty(LocalDateTime.now())
}

class MarketList : View("Markets") {
    val markets = FXCollections.observableArrayList<Market>()
    val data = SortedFilteredList<Market>(markets)

    override val root = borderpane {
        prefWidth = 500.0

        center {
            tableview(markets) {
                column<Market, LocalDateTime>("Created at", { objectBinding(it.value.updates) { first() }.select { it!!.timeProperty } })
                column<Market, LocalDateTime>("Last update", { objectBinding(it.value.updates) { last() }.select { it!!.timeProperty } })
            }
        }
        bottom {
            toolbar {
                // Click to add an update to the first entry
                button("Add update").action {
                    markets.first().updates.add(MarketUpdate())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        // Add some test entries
        markets.addAll(
                Market().apply { updates.addAll(MarketUpdate(), MarketUpdate(), MarketUpdate()) },
                Market().apply { updates.addAll(MarketUpdate(), MarketUpdate(), MarketUpdate()) },
                Market().apply { updates.addAll(MarketUpdate(), MarketUpdate(), MarketUpdate()) },
                Market().apply { updates.addAll(MarketUpdate(), MarketUpdate(), MarketUpdate()) }
        )
    }
}
```

I've used a SortedFilteredList to make it easier to deal with sorting. The reason sort works here, is that the columns are actually represented by LocalDateTime values.

[image: Resulting UI]

I hope this gives you some ideas :)

Comment: Thanks for that. It's almost 5 AM here but I will try to integrate some of those ideas after I've gotten some rest. The path I'm currently going down isn't so bad, updates are displayed and the sorting works properly in isolation but updates aren't currently triggering it, so it ends up drifting away from the sorted state. I had a hacky callback in my earlier code to solve that problem. Anyway, I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Great! I think it's best to avoid manual update code if you can rely on observable values, that's what I always aim for.

Comment: Hello again. Having an issue. The tableview doesn't automatically sort as the data changes. It's possible to manually sort using the column headers, but when the underlying data updates, the rows are not reordered. I had this problem before which is why I used the hacky callback I mentioned above, but I don't know how to solve it under these conditions. In your example, if I manually sort the "Last update" column in ascending order and press "Add update" I would expect that entire row to be moved to the bottom of the list. How can this be achieved?

Comment: The TableView doesn't reevaluate the sort criteria even when the column data changes, so you have to call sort on the TableView. A good way to do that is to create an event and fire that when you augment the data. Then you can listen to that event inside of the TableView builder and call sort: `subscribe<MarketChanged> { sort() }`

Comment: Should I be worried about a race condition? That is to say, even if all the updates to the underlying data occur on the same thread that creates the MarketChanged event, and the MarketChanged event is created last, is it possible that the MarketChanged event will be consumed before some of the column updates have taken place?

Comment: No, just make sure you add the data on the ui thread - no need to worry about race conditions.

Comment: I was ready for that to be the source of a hundred other problems, but for now the UI is still responsive enough with a simple invocation of Platform.runLater. The background thread does the REST API stuff and passes the baton off to the UI thread afterwards. But I homebrewed some simple observer logic instead of trying to use events since I didn't have a node to pretend I was firing the event from. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Events aren't fired from Nodes at all?

Comment: Oh, are you talking about a TornadoFX class called FXEvent? I may have started researching how to create a custom JavaFX Event, which a StackOverflow article indicated would be fired from a node, among other things. The mixing and matching of nomenclature can be somewhat confusing at times. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about FXEvent and the EventBus in TornadoFX :) https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-guide/blob/master/15.%20EventBus.md